# R cannot find the function .complete_args()

Tags: r

I am using the isoriX package in R and would like to update part of the source code. When I try to run it without making any changes yet, R doesn't seem to recognise any function preceded by a dot.
Am I missing any packages that should be installed in order to allow me to use those kind of functions or to update the source code?

The code I am trying to apply is quite long, but the bit R struggle with is the following function:

```r
.complete_args()
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to run code from inside a package function outside that package function? Many packages have private functions that are not exported from the package because they are not meant to be directly used anywhere else. You can access unexported function with `:::` so maybe `isoriX:::.complete_args()` might work. But it's not guarenteed that the function will behave the same if called outside the package.

Comment: There is indeed no function with that name that is exported. It might be a helper function since it shows up using `getAnywhere` but not in the functions list.

Comment: It looks like the second suggestion has worked! I will take a closer look and post back. Thank you both for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

The `isoriX:::.complete_args()` call worked.

You can access unexported function with `:::` and in my case `isoriX:::.complete_args()` worked well.